# How to restrict FROM in SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Sorry if the question's title doesn't mean anything, I'm still a beginner and I just don't know how to explain it.

Here's my current SQL query that works fine

```
select teams.id as team_id, teams.team_name, players.type_name, sum(points) as points
from teams 
inner join gameweeks on teams.id = gameweeks.team_id    
inner join gameweeks_players on gameweeks.id = gameweeks_players.gameweek_id
inner join players on gameweeks_players.player_id = players.id
inner join player_fixtures on players.id = player_fixtures.player_id AND player_fixtures.gw_number = gameweeks.number
group by teams.id, players.type_name
```

In rails, I translated this query into

```
Team.joins(gameweeks: :players).
joins("inner join player_fixtures on players.id = player_fixtures.player_id AND player_fixtures.gw_number = gameweeks.number").
group("teams.id, players.type_name").
select("teams.id, teams.team_name, players.type_name as type, sum(points) as points")
```

In rails, I have these 2 models.

```
class League < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :league_teams
    has_many :teams, :through => :league_teams
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :gameweeks
    has_many :league_teams
    has_many :leagues, :through => :league_teams
end
```

I would like to modify my query to only the teams that are associated with a league (I'd like to pass the ID of that league somehow)

I just don't know how to do that and I'm missing the knowledge to google it with the right keywords...

Could you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-where-sql-tutorial/

Comment: pretty sure what you're looking for is just `league.teams.joins(gameweeks: :players).
joins("inner join player_fixtures on players.id = player_fixtures.player_id AND player_fixtures.gw_number = gameweeks.number").
group("teams.id, players.type_name").
select("teams.id, teams.team_name, players.type_name as type, sum(points) as points")`

Comment: @RobertHarvey that doesn't help me at all. At no point the page talks about doing a where through a joint_table for example

Comment: @gregates your answer is correct too. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guide should be able to point you to the right direction:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions

I am not able to test if this works, but you could try something like this:

```
League.Team.select("teams.id, teams.team_name, players.type_name as type, sum(points) AS points")
           .joins(gameweeks: :players)
           .joins("INNER JOIN player_fixtures ON players.id = player_fixtures.player_id AND player_fixtures.gw_number = gameweeks.number")
           .where("league.id = ?", leagueId)
           .group("teams.id, players.type_name")
```

---

Edit: Merged @gregates answer from the question's comments with mine.

Comment: There was 2  small typos (league instead of leagues) but this answer worked perfectily.

@gregates answer in comment also worked.

Comment: Mine is really just the idiomatic "rails" way of doing the same thing. I'm sure you could probably eliminate even more of the raw sql from your query and make it more idiomatic with some effort (not that I'm saying it's necessarily worth it).

Comment: @gregates I agree your suggestion had a better way of doing the JOINs. I haven't coded anything with rails, so thanks for pointing that one out! There wasn't any where condition in your comment, which was something that was asked for, so I merged the solutions and updated the answer.